# ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50) for cn=config as -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL

Tags: centos6, openldap

I'm setting up a second LDAP server. I've converted a `slapd.conf` to a `slapd.d` database using `slaptest`. I'm trying to apply this LDIF:

```
# cat loglevel.ldif
dn: cn=config
changetype:modify
replace: olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel: any
```

This error comes up:

```
# ldapmodify -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -D 'cn=config' -f loglevel.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

`ldapwhoami` output:

```
# ldapwhoami -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
dn:gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
```

Config database in `slapcat -n0`:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to *  by * none
olcAddContentAcl: TRUE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config
olcRootPW:: c2VjcmV0
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcMonitoring: FALSE
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: a00805da-2405-1035-8da5-7568f1e7aea1
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20151120190701Z
entryCSN: 20151120190701.894877Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20151120190701Z
```

How do I make the command work?

Do I need to do something to enable the `-Y EXTERNAL` mechanism?

Do I need to change the `olcRootDN` property for `cn=config`? I can try changing it with a text editor in the `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current rootdn is `cn=admin,cn=config`, and your current rootpw is "secret".

SASL/EXTERNAL is enabled and working. However, the configuration of your `cn=config` database does not give `root` (aka `gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth` any special permissions.

To convert your rootdn to be local root you should run the following or its equivalent.

```
ldapmodify -D cn=admin,cn=config -w secret -H ldapi:/// <<EOF
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
replace: olcrootdn
olcrootdn: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
-
delete: olcrootpw
-
EOF
```